# Pandas Dataframe, get sum single value grouped by multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with a values column ( with array values)
I try to get sum single value grouped by multiple columns.

I use this function

```
    grouped = df_source.groupby(['filter1','filter2','filter3'])
    aggregate = list((k[0],k[1],k[2], v["Values"].apply(pd.Series).sum().to_list()) for k,v in grouped)
    return pd.DataFrame(aggregate, columns=['filter1','filter2','filter3','Values'])
```

I get the target.

Problem: when i send the dfsource  directly to get_ceded_from_df function=> the elapsed_time =127.046875

But when
1: I export the dfsource to excel file
2  I read rhe genrate excel file in a new datframe(newdf)
3: I send the newdf directly to get_ceded_from_df function=> the elapsed_time =21.047875

any Ideas?

the shape of the two dataframes(dfsource,newdf)  is the same ((13194, 5)

Comment: Are datatypes of the two dataframes the same? `dfsource.dtypes`, `newdf.dtypes`

Comment: @Vladimir Fokow : Yes